# Getting errors in jsp for netbeans 7.3.1

Tags: jsp, netbeans

I am getting error in netbeans 7.3.1 with below jsp code.
It works fine with netbeans 6.x version

```
<logic:iterate id="format" name ="format" type="LeafletFormat">

<html:option value="<%=String.valueOf(format.getValue())%>">

            <%= format.toString() %>
  </html:option> 
--
--
</logic>
```

I am getting error at word format, It says cant find symbol, variable format.
FYI- I have imported in above in jsp

Comment: where is JSP code? Where `format` variable is declared in JSP file?

Comment: <logic:iterate id="format" name ="format" type="LeafletFormat">
<html:option value="<%=String.valueOf(format.getValue())%>">
            <%= format.toString() %>
  </html:option> 
--
--
</logic>

Comment: Yuck; scriptlets. Consider doing the work outside of the view layer.

Comment: Same works for previous versions of netbeans , i.e. 5.5 and 6.x

Comment: <logic:iterate id="format" name ="format" type="LeafletFormat">

<html:option value="<%=String.valueOf(format.getValue())%>">

            <%= format.toString() %>
  </html:option> 
--
--
</logic>

Comment: I am getting errors in <html:option value="<%=String.valueOf(format.getValue())%>">  and <%= format.toString() %>

Comment: It says cant find symbol variable format, Also it compils fine, but while running it gives a blank page

Comment: Can anyone help please